# How to keep CSS class on menu item with dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hidden dropdown that shows when a `<li>` is hovered. Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="products">
        <a href="products.php">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="about.php">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="nav-products">
    <p>Search by part number or product name:</p>
</div>
```

When it is hovered, the class `.active` is added to the `<li>`. Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".products").mouseover(function () {
    $("#nav-products").show();
    $(".products").addClass('active');
});
$(".products, #nav-products").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#nav-products").hide();    
});
$("#nav-products").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).show();
});
$("#nav-products").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".products").removeClass('active');
});
```

it works great *except* that if I exit the dropdown `<div>` through `li.products`, `li.products` keeps the `.active` class. I have tried adding in another function at different points-

```
$(".products").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

with no luck. I realize this basic question has been asked a ton of times here. I've used many other answers to get this far, but this last issue is something I cannot figure out.

How can I get `li.products` to drop the `.active` class on mouseleave while keeping `.active` if the mouse goes into `#nav-products`?

Comment: You cannot have 2 of the same events on the same object. Referring to `mouseleave` on `#nav-products`

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="products">
        <a href="products.php">Products</a>
        <div id="nav-products" style='display:none'>
           <p>Search by part number or product name:</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="about.php">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(".products").hover(function () {
  $("#nav-products").toggle();
  $(".products").toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. #nav-products does not stay visible when the mouse goes off of .products

Comment: The edit will allow the #nav-products to stay visible after mouse goes away from .products. What other classes/visibility do you need beyond this?

Comment: This is closer, but not what I need. I need .products to keep .active on mouseleave, but only when the cursor enters into #nav-products. If the cursor Ieaves going outside of .products OR #nav-products, then #nav-products should hide and .products should have .active removed.

Comment: How does the mouse enter into #nav-products? Since #nav-products and .products are not next to each other, when mouse leaves .products, #nav-products becomes invisible. Are #nav-products and .products together somehow?

Comment: Yes, #nav-products looks like it is a direct dropdown menu of .products. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I think I will try putting #nav-products inside the .products <li>.

Comment: So I've edited the answer, can you see if that's what you need?

Comment: If you want to up vote the answer too that'd be appreciated. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just nest your dropdown inside the list item.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Nav Item 1
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li>Sub Item</li>
      <li>Sub Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Nav Item 2
  </li>
  <li>
    Nav Item 2
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is Your example code

```js
$(".products").mouseover(function() {
    $("#nav-products").show();
    $(".products").addClass('active');
});
$(".products, #nav-products").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#nav-products").hide();
});
$("#nav-products").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).show();
});
$("#nav-products").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".products").removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="products">
      <a href="products.php">Products</a>
      <div id="nav-products">
          <a href="#">Search by part number or product name:</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.php">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd prefer to have the #nav-products div outside of the <li> due to the design. There's gotta be a way to do this without nesting it.

Comment: I tried your method--moving #nav-producst inside the <li.products>-- and the .active class still stays on .products when the mouse leaves it. Seems to work the same as my original code. Same problem exists.